# Why doesn't number1 and number2 have to be declared in this java code?

Tags: java

This code is a small lab in class, and saw that in method int add() number1 and 2 weren't declared. Can someone tell me why that is?

```
public class htc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n1 = 4;
    int n2 = 5;
    int n3 = add(n1, n2);
    int result = add(n2, add(add(9, add(2, n3)), 3));
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static int add(int number1, int number2) {
    int sum = number1 + number2;
    return sum;
}
}
```

Comment: I can see `int number1` and `int number` declared as parameters for `public static int add` method. What's your question?

Comment: They are declared, they are declared as parameter variables for `add`, which gives them local context to the `add` method...

Comment: Ok never mind, I somehow missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number1` and `number2` are both parameters. Parameters are declared when you write:

```
(int number1, int number2)
```

This means that whenever you call the function, you are passing values into those two variables automatically as parameters.

For example, when you write: `add(n1, n2)` you are telling it to run that function and substitute n1 in for number1 and n2 in for number2.

Comment: actually "copy the value of n1 to number1 and n2 to number2" to be strict ("substitute" could mean passing the reference which is not true).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int add(int number1, int number2)
```

This code means that you are declaring number1 and number2 since you have 'int' in front of them though they dont have any value in them yet.
But this add function is called when you call the function add from main() and compiling starts from main() so when you call that function from main() then the parameters of add function gets initialised with values from n2 and add(add(9, add(2, n3)), 3)) so number1 and number2 have a defined value in them now.So the code executes without any error.Hope you understand now.